# Problema de rendimiento con una consulta UPDATE

Tags: php, sql, update, rendimiento

Tengo un en un script PHP un fragmento como el siguiente:

```
foreach ($externos as $keyExt => $ext) {
    $consulta = "UPDATE asociaciones SET ";
    $consulta .= "id_de_contrato = '".$ext['id_de_area']."' ";
    $consulta .= "WHERE id_de_trabajador = '".$ext['id_de_trabajador']."';";
    $conexionPDO->query($consulta);
}
```

El problema es que la matriz `$externos` tiene varios miles de elementos, con lo que, al entrar en el bucle, colapsa. Como puedo replantear el UPDATE para que sea más ligero?

Comment: Puedes hacer al menos 3 cosas para optimizar tu consulta: 1. Revisar que tienes los índices correctos en tu tabla; 2. Escribir una consulta preparada; 3. Pensar en normalizar y/o resolver esto de otro modo, definiendo reglas de integridad referencial en las tablas o escribiendo un TRIGGER que mantenga los datos al día (es raro tener que necesitar una consulta que haga actualizaciones masivas). Esto último quizá sea lo mejor, pues me pregunto: ¿por qué estos datos no están ya actualizados, por qué hay que actualizarlos de este modo?

Comment: Cabe decir que los problemas pueden ser otros: una conexión de red muy lenta, un servidor con demasiadas limitaciones o mal configurado, etc, etc, etc. Lo cierto es que una consulta como la tuya, si los índices están bien puestos en la tabla, no debería dar ningún problema en un servidor decente, incluso si tuviera que actualizar varios cientos de miles de registros en esta consulta. Si la consulta es lenta, debes revisar los índices y demás. Por cierto, dinos con qué SGBD estás trabajando para que te podamos sugerir formas de optimizar/verificar el estado de tu BD.

Comment: Y si tenes varios miles de elementos, estas segura que la mejor solucion es un script en php?

Comment: Si la fuente de $externos es la misma base de datos, con un JOIN ahorrarás considerablemente.